# youtube url rel=0 is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, youtube-javascript-api

youtube url is not working in javascript,why?
       where is the mistake in my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
  api_images = ['http://www.youtube.com/watchv=OyQoHmcunk&amp;rel=0&amp;fs=0&amp;width=640&amp;height=360'];
 api_titles = ['Title 1'];
 api_descriptions = ['']
 $.prettyPhoto.open(api_images,api_titles,api_descriptions);
 });
```

Comment: You shouldn't have changed your question so the mistake is gone.  You should leave it there so this page makes sense to other people in the future.

Comment: Rolled back to demonstrate the error, which is addressed in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `?` that actually separates the path from the query-string:

```
api_images = ['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyQoHmcunk&amp;rel=0&amp;fs=0&amp;width=640&amp;height=360'];
//                                         ^
```

Without it, you should be receiving a 404 response, which a decent javascript debugger would've told you. You are using a debugger, [right](http://www.browserstack.com/debugging-tools)?

Also, depending on the `DOCTYPE` in use and whether this is from an inline or external `<script>`, HTML-encoding the `&`s may either be necessary or another source of issue:

```
api_images = ['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyQoHmcunk&rel=0&fs=0&width=640&height=360'];
//                                                      ^     ^    ^         ^
```